# Where is the sudoers file on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, sudoers, debian-buster

There is a server that was setup a while back, and I need to change a few settings, one of which is a user with super user privileges. However, everywhere I look tell to use `visudo`, or edit `/etc/sudoers`, but **none of these things** exist on this server.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
$ whereis visudo
visudo:
$ visudo
-bash: visudo: command not found
$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
ls: cannot access '/etc/sudoers': No such file or directory
```

Where would that configuration be?

#### ** EDIT **

To be clear, the user can `su` without a password, so that's setup somewhere, but since `/etc/sudoers` does not exist, and `visudo` is not installed (neither is `sudo`), where would that config be?

Comment: Is `sudo` installed?

Comment: No, it isn't. But `su` works without requiring a password.

Comment: `su` is entirely unrelated to `sudo`. Please provide the contents of `/etc/pam.d/su`.

Comment: Do a `whoami` and let us know what UID it tells you that you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To be clear, the user can su without a password, so that's setup somewhere,

Somewhere else than sudoers, certainly. They are completely independent commands – `su` has its own logic for granting root rights and does not use 'sudo' or 'sudoers' for *anything*, whether it's passwordless or not. They just have similar names.

The regular Linux 'su' mostly relies on PAM configuration: if you can pass the PAM authentication, then you can get root privileges. Now *usually* this is set up to call your usual password-checking module (pam_unix or other), but other modules can be used as well – indeed the default `/etc/pam.d/su` often has an example of exactly the kind of passwordless mode that you're looking for:

*Default /etc/pam.d/su from Arch Linux:*

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so
```

So if your 'su' is passwordless, chances are it uses pam_wheel in its PAM stack (/etc/pam.d/su). Check if that's the case, and if so, use `gpasswd` to add or remove people from the "wheel" group.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `visudo` and the `sudoers` file because you don't have `sudo` installed. Install it with this command as root:

```
apt install sudo
```

Comment: How could the user be able to `su` without password without `sudo` installed? The point is: this was done without `sudo`, so where is that config set?